# How plot json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, flotr, flotr2

I'm getting every 4 secs a json data like this:

```
{
   "time": "04:49:07 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1375246147254,
   "date": "07-31-2013"
}
```

I'm processing it in order to get a array like this:

> [[1375230673948, 0.6443498175195954]]

(The first data is a js timestamp)

I'm trying to plot these data, on real time using flot:

```
function draw() {
    console.log('draw called');
    this.array = getTimeArray();
    $.plot(
    $("#placeholder"), [
        {
        label: "test Data",
        data: this.array,
        lines: {
            show: true,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: "rgba(249, 28, 61,0.3)",
            lineWidth: 2.5
        },
        }
    ], {
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%H:%M"
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: -2
        }
    });
}

function getTimeArray(flg) {

    var array = [],
    d = new Date(),
    tz = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    jsonUrl = 'http://date.jsontest.com/'
    var array2 = []
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data) {
        var i = 0;
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if (typeof val === 'number'){
                    d = new Date(val - 5 * 60 * 1000);
                    array2.push([d.getTime()- tz*60*1000,Math.random()]);
                    console.log(array2)
                    i++;
                }
            });
     });

    for (var i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        d = new Date(d.getTime() - 5 * 60 * 1000);
        array.push([d.getTime() - tz*60*1000, Math.random()]);
    }
    return array;
}

draw();
setInterval(draw, 4000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gKRPX/28/

But I can't get it yet, please could somebody help me?

I need plot the time series with their values getting the data from 
json.Maybe using another lib it could be reached more easily, any help are welcome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `$.getJSON` call is asynchronous, so if you try to return `array2` (in the jsFiddle), it is an empty list. You need to use either the `success` callback or the `.done()` method to draw the plot, after getting JSON data from the server:

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function (jdata) {
    var i = 0;
    $.each(jdata, function (key, val) {
        if (typeof val === 'number') {
            d = new Date(val - 5 * 60 * 1000);
            if (array.length > 9) {
                array.shift();
            }
            array.push([d.getTime() - tz * 60 * 1000, Math.random()]);
            i++;
        }
    });

}).done(function (jdata) {
    data[0]["data"] = array;
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
});
```

You can see the [full jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKRPX/30/). I keep pushing to the array and shift it when its length gets above 9, just to illustrate.

You can also use the `setData` and `draw` methods of the flot plot to avoid drawing the plot every time, but that's a different issue.